# How to use invokedynamic to execute method with polymorphism?

Tags: java, invokedynamic

In a dynamic language for Java where all variables are declared as `java.lang.Object`, I need to call Java built-in classes.  For example, `java.math.BigDecimal` constructor can accept number, String and etc.

```
a = 10  // a is `java.lang.Object`
create java.math.BigDecimal(a)  // should call constructor that accept number
a = '1.234'  // a is `java.lang.Object`
create java.math.BigDecimal(a)  // should call constructor that accept String
```

Are there `java.lang.invoke` that I can use to generate appropriate `MethodHandle`? The `MethodHandle` should accept an `java.lang.Object` as its argument, but when invoked, it should call the proper constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java reflection, for example using [ConstructorUtils.invokeConstructor(...)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/ConstructorUtils.html#invokeConstructor%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Comment: Should I use `invokestatic` to directly call `ConstructorUtils.invokeConstructor()` or should I still use `invokedynamic` and specify `ConstructorUtils.invokeConstructor()` as call site target?  Which one is preferable?

Comment: For static methods you can use methods from `MethodUtils`... In order to create `BigDecimal` object `BigDecimal.valueOf(...)` is more preferable way http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double).

Comment: Actually I'm talking about bytecode genaration.  If unable to find a way to take the benefit of Java 7 `invokedynamic` API, I will use the reflection API.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to create an *inline cache*.  Initially, your bootstrap method will return a call site bound to a method handle that inspects its argument type, locates the proper constructor on BigInteger (or whatever type -- pass this type as a static argument to the bootstrap method), and re-links the call site to first check for this type and call the right constructor, or fall back to looking up the constructor again.  Thus if that call site only passes Strings, you only perform the reflective search for a constructor once, and further calls are just a type check and direct call to the constructor.  (This is very similar to what the JVM does to inline virtual method calls.)

I don't know invokedynamic well enough to give you example code for this, but I can point you to the [JSR 252 Cookbook](https://code.google.com/p/jsr292-cookbook/source/browse/trunk/inlining-cache/src/jsr292/cookbook/icache/RT.java) doing something similar, which is documented with a [talk from the JVM Language Summit 2011](http://medianetwork.oracle.com/video/player/1113248965001) and [accompanying slides](http://www.wiki.jvmlangsummit.com/images/9/93/2011_Forax.pdf).